# What is the geometric meaning of $H^2(X, \mathscr{O}_X)$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, cohomology

Let $X$ be a compact complex manifold with structure sheaf $\mathscr{O}_X$ (the sheaf of holomorphic functions on $X$).

> What is the geometric meaning (if any) of $H^2(X, \mathscr{O}_X)$?

In the [comments](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/412512/what-is-the-geometric-meaning-of-h2x-mathscro-x#comment1057131_412512), Piotr Achinger mentions that $H^2(X, \mathscr{O}_X)$ is the tangent space of the (formal) Brauer group. Let me ask a follow up question:

> What is the geometric meaning (if any) of $H^2(X, \mathscr{O}_X)$ if the Brauer group, and the cohomological Brauer group are both trivial?

Comment: It is the tangent space of the (formal) Brauer group. It contains obstruction classes to deforming line bundles on $X$ to infinitesimal deformations.

Comment: @PiotrAchinger Dear Piotr, thank you for this! I was not aware of Brauer groups at all and have begun looking into them. Do you have a reference suggestion for using Brauer groups to study the geometry of a complex manifold? I'm admittedly far from knowledgable about number theory and my understanding of commutative algebra is only at a working level (although, this is a great excuse to learn more!) :)

Comment: For others that may be interested: A nice reference for the geometric side looks like Schröer's Topological Methods for complex-analytic Brauer groups -- https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0405223.pdf It is very well-written from what I have seen so far.

Comment: It classifies gerbes with band $\mathbb{C}$ (also look at bundle gerbes).

Comment: For the follow up question I encourage you to take a look at the cohomology sequence from the exponential sequence.

Comment: @PiotrAchinger Sorry for my ignorance: what do you mean by "the tangent space of the (formal) Brauer group"? I imagine that it might be related to the stack $B^2\mathbb G_m$, but I don't see what kind of tangent should we consider?

Comment: @Z.M Take the identity in $B^2\mathbb{G}_m$ as a $2$-group and look at the formal neighbourhood around it. That's the formal thing. Truncate it by killing the squares in the horizontal direction. That's the tangent space. Maybe it's a good idea to take a look at the usual definitions of a formal moduli problem. See, for instance, Lurie's ICM https://www.math.ias.edu/~lurie/papers/moduli.pdf . If you're unfamiliar with the basics of $\infty$/derived stuff, it's a good idea to start with the cotangent complex. See also https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Brauer+stack .

Comment: @Z.M No derived stuff necessary! Simply consider the functor associating to an Artinian local complex algebra $A$ the kernel of $H^2(X_A, O^*)\to H^2(X, O^*)$. In good cases (e.g. $H^1(X, O_X)=0$) this is representable by a formal group called by Artin and Mazur the formal Brauer group of $X$. Its tangent space is $H^2(X, O_X)$.

Comment: @PiotrAchinger Thank you for these comments, what if $H^1(X, \mathscr{O}_X) \simeq H^1(X, \mathscr{O}_X^{\ast})$, but is non-zero; is this a _bad case_?

Comment: @JLA Thank you for this comment, I will look into gerbes and bundle gerbes.

Comment: @AmorFati: I don't think that can happen. If $H^1(X,\mathscr O_X)$ embeds into $H^1(X, \mathscr O_X^*)$, then $H^1(X,\mathbb Z)=0$, but then $H^1(X,\mathbb C)=0$, so $H^1(X,\mathscr O_X)=0$.

Comment: @user40276 Is something like the tangent of $B^nG$ at origin is the $n$-th shift of the tangent of $G$ at the origin for abelian group scheme $G$ (I guess that this is how $\mathbb G_a$ and $\mathbb G_m$ relate)? If so, is there any obvious reason? (I asked about tangent because I find it counterintuitive that the tangent of $G$ is specific at a chosen point $e$, although in the abelian case, the conjugation action is trivial, but in the formulation of the tangent $BG$ at the origin, there seems no preferred choice like that of $e$).

Comment: @SándorKovács Dear Sándor, thank you for your comment. For a _non-Kähler_ complex manifold, one could certainly have $H^1(X, \mathbb{Z})=0$ without $H^1(X, \mathscr{O}_X)=0$. I'm primarily interested in the _non-Kähler_ case.

Comment: @AmorFati, uh, ok, I should read the question more carefully. :)

Comment: ps: @AmorFati, so perhaps it *is* a bad case... :)

Comment: @Z.M Yes. For any say affine algebraic $G$, the cotangent complex of $B^nG$ is the shifted dual Lie algebra with the coadjoint representation (notice that qcoh modules over $BG$ are exactly$G$-representations). I don't get exactly what you mention to be counter-intuitive. What's in being taken is the formal neighborhood of $B^2\mathbb{G}_m$ around the identity, so there's only the identity and a bunch of infinitesimal stuff. A formal group over say $Spec (\mathbb{C})$ has only one closed point.

Comment: @SándorKovács It just goes to show how important the Hodge decomposition is. Alternatively, how deluded we are by the Hodge decomposition :)

Comment: @user40276 Basically, I did not believe that the formal neighborhood of $BG$ is determined by the formal neighborhood of $G$ at origin. Is the assertion about $B^nG$ true when the cotangent complex of $G$ is not bounded, or even not of finite Tor-amplitude (I am thinking about the base being an affine scheme like $\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb Z)$, not necessarily a field of char 0), and you seem to indicate that $B^nG$ makes sense even when $G$ is not commutative (or "$E_n$")?

Comment: @Z.M I think we should discuss this elsewhere. I guess we are spamming the thread. Can you create a chat room? I don't know how to do that... For now, I say the following 1) The cotangent complex is almost always perfect  2) Deloopings exist in the general setting of $\infty$-topoi for any internal group